# C# Maze Game Inquiry

Tags: c#, maze

So I am creating a Maze Game in Visual Studio, coding in C#. I am moving along nicely, but I am stuck on figuring out how to make the walls of the maze solid. Currently when you reach a wall in the maze, the place marker goes right through them and deletes the blue colored walls. I am currently trying to figure how to make the walls where you can't pass through them. I have tried various statements and also tried messing with the unicode and can't seem to get anywhere. If anyone has any tips, that would be great! Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Project4
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.SetWindowSize(10, 10);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;

        //Make maze
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine(" \u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588 ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \u2588\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u2588 ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \u2588\u0020\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u0020\u2588 ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \u2588\u0020\u2588\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u2588 ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \u2588\u0020\u2588\u0020\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588 ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \u2588\u0020\u2588\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u2588 ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \u2588\u0020\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u0020\u2588 ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \u2588\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u2588 ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588 ");
        Console.Write("");

        int col = 7;
        int row = 6;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
        Console.Write("*");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.W)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
                Debug.Print("W");
                row--;
            }
            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Z)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
                Debug.Print("Z");
                row++;
            }

            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
                Debug.Print("A");
                col--;
            }

            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
                Debug.Print("S");
                col++;
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
            Console.Write("*");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am creating a Maze Game in VB, coding in C#"... huh?

Comment: *VS Visual Studio...my bad haha

Comment: I would suggest making a model of your maze that isn't the display. Write a method to render the model to the display. Then figure out the rules that apply to your model rather than testing the UI.

Comment: Could you please clarify that a little bit? Thanks

Comment: Spender means separate the maze logic from the displaying. Store the maze data as a class of some kind that you can test for things like hitting the wall. You then can write a function that takes the information from the maze class and draws it on the screen.

Comment: Is there any way that you can provide me with an example? Because I am honestly lost haha.

Comment: See my answer below - you can walk around the maze, and the walls are solid. Now please upvote it because I'm 4 rep points off 1000. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making an array to hold your map, and writing a method to render your game:

```
void Main()
{
    var map=new[]
    {
        new[]{true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true}, 
        new[]{true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true}, 
        new[]{true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true}, 
        new[]{true, false, true, false, false, false, false, true}, 
        new[]{true, false, true, false, true, true, true, true}, 
        new[]{true, false, true, false, false, false, false, true}, 
        new[]{true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true}, 
        new[]{true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true}, 
        new[]{true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true}
    };
    var playerX = 1;
    var playerY = 1;
    RenderMap(map, playerX, playerY);

}

void RenderMap(bool[][] map, int playerX, int playerY)
{

    for(var y = 0; y < map.Length; y++)
    {
        var row = map[y];
        for(var x = 0; x < row.Length; x++)
        {
            var tile = row[x];
            if(x == playerX && y == playerY)
            {
                Console.Write("X");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(tile? "\u2588": " ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Now you can do things like:

```
if(map[playerY][playerX-1])
{
    //there is a wall to the left of the player's current position
}
```

...if I go any further, I've written your program for you, but this should get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is it really that complex? Isn't there a statement, or an edit to the number of row and column length or something that I can do to make the walls "solid"?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking for. Programming is "complex", and you need to decide whether to step-up or stick with your own broken design. I've just handed you everything you need on a plate. Good luck.

Comment: @user2896609 You're writing text on the screen.  Neither text nor screen have any concept of 'solid' so you need to write code to define that for your program.

Answer (score 0):

To make the walls 'solid' basically means forbidding moves which would make your cursor position overlap with a wall. Consider the following solution:

```
class Program
{
    private const char wallchar = '\u2588';
    private const char mazechar = '\u0020';

    static private bool[][] mazeLayout = 
    {
        new[] {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true},
        new[] {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true},
        new[] {true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true},
        new[] {true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true},
        new[] {true, false, true, false, false, false, false, true},
        new[] {true, false, true, false, true, true, true, true},
        new[] {true, false, true, false, false, false, false, true},
        new[] {true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true},
        new[] {true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true},
        new[] {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true}
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.SetWindowSize(10, 10);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;

        Console.WriteLine("");

        //Make maze
        for (int i = 0; i < mazeLayout.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mazeLayout[i].Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(mazeLayout[i][j] ? wallchar : mazechar);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
        int col = 3;
        int row = 6;

        Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
        Console.Write("*");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.W && !mazeLayout[row - 2][col])
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
                Debug.Print("W");
                row--;
            }
            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Z && !mazeLayout[row][col])
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
                Debug.Print("Z");
                row++;
            }

            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.A && !mazeLayout[row-1][col-1])
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
                Debug.Print("A");
                col--;
            }

            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.S && !mazeLayout[row-1][col+1])
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
                Debug.Print("S");
                col++;
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
            Console.Write("*");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
        }
    }
}
```

The line:

```
if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.S && !mazeLayout[row-1][col+1])
{ ... }
```

means:

```
if (the user pressed S) AND (the move would not move us onto a wall)
then... 
    { go ahead and do the move. }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there not a way that I can implement this strategy without changing my whole code around?

Comment: You're welcome! :) This code is based on your code, it works (and is actually a playable game!), and the only changes are design improvements to certain areas, such as separating the data (true false array) from the presentation. This separation is necessary to provide a way of checking for walls, so I don't think there is a much simpler way to change your code to get it working how you want.

Comment: Thanks for improving it and all, but is there not a way to do it without the true/false array statement. Like just keep the unicode as the core map design?

Comment: You can make the array of data any type you like. But you really have to have a data block, which is separate to the code which displays the maze. Extracting it to true/false boolean array just makes the most sense, logically. I'm not sure why you'd want the old structure. Having said that, if you can understand how the code above works, you will be quite able to work the rest out yourself. :)